GBTClassifier from pyspark mllib Model evaluation on highly imbalanced dataset excludes one class prediction
I have a highly imbalanced dataset on which I need to do a binary classification. I had to find techniques to resample the dataset without having to convert my pyspark dataframe to pandas dataframe (it's simpler for smaller datasets but we want to get the most out of spark).
What I mostly found on the internet is to split my dataset into train and test, do the resampling only on the train data, fit the model to it then predict on the train data which are not resampled (biased to 0 class).
I used GBTClassifier from pyspark mllib and evaluated it and got the area under ROC value of 0.91
however, while trying to show the confusion matrix, it only showed 0 as the predicted value:
+----------------+---------+
|label_prediction|      0.0|
+----------------+---------+
|               0|156943724|
|               1|   819045|
+----------------+---------+
when I search the reason that might be behind this is that the test data is biased to one class so it won't show the other one as it does not have predictions to it.
so my question is: is it right to resample only the train part of the data or should the test data be resampled too ?
